# Когда лучше употреблять self join, а когда иерархический запрос?

Tags: sql, рекурсия

Не могу понять, когда лучше использовать self join, а когда иерархический запрос (рекурсивный), объясните пожалуйста

Comment: самосоединение когда уровень вложенности мал и ограничен, в остальных случаях рекурсивный запрос

Comment: На заметку: существует несколько способов хранения иерархий в РСУБД (четыере основных и комбинации). И для работы с ними вполне можно обходиться без self join и рекурсий.

Answer (score 1):

Self join - это присоединение таблицу к самой себе. Это нужно, чтобы сравнить данные в одной таблице с другими данными в ней же. А иерархический запрос- это способ получить данные из таблицы, которая имеет ссылку на саму себя.

Вот наглядные примеры.

Self join:
Вы хотите найти все пары сотрудников, которые работают в одной и той же должности.
Запрос:

```
SELECT e1.name, e2.name FROM employees e1
JOIN employees e2
ON e1.position = e2.position AND e1.employee_id != e2.employee_id
```

Иерархический:
Вы хотите найти всех подчиненных у директора компании.
Запрос:

```
WITH RECURSIVE employee_hierarchy(name, manager) AS (
SELECT name, manager FROM employees
WHERE manager IS NULL
UNION
SELECT e.name, e.manager FROM employees e
JOIN employee_hierarchy eh ON e.manager = eh.name
)
SELECT * FROM employee_hierarchy WHERE manager = 'Director'
```

В 1 примере мы используем соединение таблицы с самой собой (self join) для поиска сотрудников с одинаковой должностью. Во 2 примере мы используем рекурсивный запрос для поиска подчиненных у директора компании.

Comment: Но и иерархический вариант можно сделать через несколько self join, допустим во view несколько таблиц, проще же сделать пару self join, чем иерархический запрос.
или от ситуации зависит?

Comment: Да, в некоторых случаях можно использовать несколько self join для решения задачи, которая может быть решена иерархическим запросом. Но иерархический запрос может быть более простым и читаемым, если данные имеют связи с самими собой. В зависимости от ситуации, можно выбрать лучший вариант запроса для конкретной задачи и данных.